# Apex class which uploads document error: The MAC signature found in the HTTP request '' is not the same as any computed signature

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, apex

I want to upload documents to Azure Blob with Apex code.

I have below Apex class which uploads document to Azure but gives error

> "The MAC signature found in the HTTP request '' is not the same as any computed signature".

I am not sure where I am messing up the HTTP Authentication header. I did use this code from https://stackoverflow.com.

```
public class AzureService {

    private String storageKey;
    private String storageName;
    private String storageContainer;
    private String storageUrl;
    private String blobName;
    private String requestURL;
    private String fileLength;
    private String formattedDate ;
    private String fileType;
    private String fileName;


    private final string DATEFORMAT = 'EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z';
    private final string VERSION = '2015-12-11';
    private final string BLOB_TYPE = 'BlockBlob';


    public Boolean uploadBlob( Blob fileBody, Integer intFileLength, String strFileType, String strFileName)
    {

        Boolean isUploaded= false;
        this.fileName = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(strFileName, 'UTF-8');
        this.fileType = strFileType;
        this.storageName = 'STORAGE_ACCOUNT';
        this.storageContainer = 'CONTAINER_NAME';
        this.storageKey = 'ACCESS_KEY';
        this.storageUrl ='https://STORAGE_ACCOUNT.blob.core.windows.net';

        this.blobName = '/'+storageName+'/'+storageContainer+'/'+fileName;
        System.debug('blobName--->'+blobName);
        this.requestURL = storageUrl+'/'+storageContainer+'/'+fileName;
        System.debug('requestURL--->'+requestURL);

        this.fileLength = String.valueof(intFileLength);

        String strSharedKey = getBlobSharedKey();

        try
        {
            this.uploadBlob(fileBody, strSharedKey);
            isUploaded = true;

        }catch(Exception exp)
        {
            System.debug('Exception occur while uploading the Blob-->'+exp.getMessage());
            isUploaded = false;
        }

        return isUploaded;
    }


    public String getBlobSharedKey()
    {
        System.debug('getBlobSharedKey--->Start');
        String sharedKey;
        String signature;
        Datetime dt = Datetime.now();

        this.formattedDate = dt.formatGMT(DATEFORMAT);
        String stringToSign = 'PUT\n\n\n'+fileLength+'\n\n'+fileType+'\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob\nx-ms-date:'+formattedDate+'\nx-ms-version:2015-12-11\n'+blobName;

        System.debug('stringToSign--->'+stringToSign);

        Blob unicodeKey = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(storageKey);
        Blob data = Crypto.generateMac('hmacSHA256', Blob.valueOf(stringToSign), unicodeKey);
        signature = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(data);

        sharedKey = 'SharedKey '+storageName+':' + signature;
        return sharedKey;
    }

   public void uploadBlob(Blob fileBody, String sharedKey)
   {
       HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();


       req.setMethod('PUT');

       req.setHeader('x-ms-blob-type', BLOB_TYPE);
       req.setHeader('x-ms-version', VERSION);
       req.setHeader('x-ms-date', formattedDate);
       req.setHeader('Authorization', sharedKey);
       req.setHeader('Content-Type', fileType);
       req.setHeader('Content-Length', fileLength);

       req.setEndpoint(this.requestURL);

       req.setBodyAsBlob(fileBody);

       Http http = new Http();
       HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
       // in the response body you have your blob
       System.debug('Response Body--->'+res.getBody());
       System.debug('Status--->'+res.getStatus());

   }

}
```

Comment: In your error response you should see the value used by Azure Storage Service for `stringToSign`. Compare that with the value of `stringToSign` you're computing. Both of them should exactly match.

Comment: Man! you are awesome. Thank you so much. I was entering Filelenght as 168 and it was actually 126. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you  [Gaurav Mantri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188096/gaurav-mantri) for your suggestion .Converting it as answer to help other community members.

Please check with value used for **`stringToSign`** by Azure Storage Service. Compare that with the value of **`stringToSign`** you're computing. Both of them should exactly match